# Distributing push notifications on multiple workers

Tags: mysql, django, celery, django-celery

Say you have millions of Android GCM device keys and you want to send them in a management script. This script will take loads of time to finish as it's processing the keys in the DB as a queue.

**Question:** How do you implement this faster? how do you send these notifications in parallel? how do you get to near-real-time push notifications?

One solution would to to instantiate an X number of celery workers where each worker is responsible for an offset Y at which it starts fetching from MySQL. 
Example:

```
Worker 1: starts at offset 0,
Worker 2: starts at offset 10,000,
Worker 3: starts at offset 20,000,
Worker 4: starts at offset 30,000,
Worker 5: starts at offset 40,000,

Worker 1: Restarts at offset 50,000,
Worker 2: Restarts at offset 60,000,
```

... etc

Is this a viable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create list of tasks as a [Celery group](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups). Also because you have to retrieve all records from Android model it's good to create separate celery task which will do it in background:

```
@shared_task
def push_notification(offset, limit):
   for android in Android.objects.all()[offset:offset+limit]:
       pass

@shared_task
def push_notification_to_all():
   count = Android.objects.all().count()
   limit = 100
   group(push_notification.s(offset, limit) for offset in range(0, count, limit)()

push_notification_to_all.delay()
```

Also instead of sending

Comment: Does this scale? i think looping through millions of records and creating millions of pending tasks would load up the server don't you think?

Comment: If you are using RabbitMQ you should be fine. However, if you are afraid of sending too many messages at once you can split `push_notification_all()` in smaller batches.

Comment: I've modified code to present different approach. Instead of sending thousands of keys from one task to another you can send offset and limit values and loop through objects retrieved straight from database. If the number of messages will grow to high, you can adjust limit value to higher one.